# Drawing phase portrait of a system of three nonlinear ODEs using MATLAB.

Tags: numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system, optimal-control

I have the following system of ODE in three equations and I need to see the phase portrait of the system by using MATLAB (I have MATLAB R2019a). But I don't know how to code this system in to a MATLAB. Can anyone help me how I do that? Thank you in advance.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dfrac{dx}{dt}&=x(0.45-0.36x-0.05y-0.00001z)\\
\dfrac{dy}{dt}&=y(0.04x-0.000005z-0.003)\\
\dfrac{dz}{dt}&=42+0.005xy-z(0.008x+0.006y+0.0013)\\
&x(0)>0, ~~y(0)>0, ~~z(0)>0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: You mean something like the quiver function in matlab, or in your case [quiver3](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver3.html)?

Comment: @Moo No No am saying 42, it has physical meaning in this model

Comment: @Moo: Okay good, i need that one. Please write me the code you use to draw in mathematica.